# Conditionally include html table with r objects in rmarkdown?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm working on a automatically generating a series of dynamic reports with Rmarkdown. The majority of the reports include a table on a single question, although there are several cases with multiple questions (see below). Because the reports are dynamically generated, the content for the html table depends on an r object.

How can I set up my rmarkdown html to conditionally evaluate and show the second table when appropriate (via an argument like "eval = has_two_qs" or something)? I've tried changing the chunk options using "asis" or "echo", but then it doesn't trigger the r objects (eg `r q2_text` is shown literally - not the actual q2_text as specified in the params). I've also tried directly showing sections of the html table by including data-show-if inside of a div, but that's not getting me where I want either.

Example (works as expected, all reports have Q1):

```
<table border=1 frame=hsides rules=rows>  
  <tr>
    <td>Q1</td>
    <td>`r q1_text`</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Q1 key</td>
    <td>`r q1_answers`</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Q1 percent correct</td>
    <td>`r q1_pct_correct`</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The part I'm having difficulty with (with failed options in quotes, as I don't know how to get them to show via markdown here):

````
# ```(asis, echo = has_two_qs) # 
<table border=1 frame=hsides rules=rows>  
  <tr>
    <td>Q2</td>
    <td>`r q2_text`</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Q2 key</td>
    <td>`r q2_answers`</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Q2 percent correct</td>
    <td>`r q2_pct_correct`</td>
  </tr>
</table>
````

Also doesn't work:

```
<div data-show-if="has_two_qs">
<table border=1 frame=hsides rules=rows>  
  <tr>
    <td>Q2</td>
    <td>`r q2_text`</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Q2 key</td>
    <td>`r q2_answers`</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Q2 percent correct</td>
    <td>`r q2_pct_correct`</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: I have an idea in mind, but it depends on how the table is being produced. Can you store the table output in variable?

Comment: This may be helpful https://www.nagraj.net/notes/conditional-r-markdown/

Comment: @guasi I hadn't thought about storing the table output as a variable, but I'm happy to give it a try. Also thank you for the link!

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires the `htmltools` package. If you can store the output of the table in a variable, then you can have an if statement that prints the output.

```
{r echo=FALSE}
library(htmltools)
table_q2 = NULL
table_q2 <- "<table border=1 frame=hsides rules=rows>  
  <tr>
    <td>Q2</td>
    <td>`r q2_text`</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Q2 key</td>
    <td>`r q2_answers`</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Q2 percent correct</td>
    <td>`r q2_pct_correct`</td>
  </tr>
</table>"
```

```
{r echo=FALSE}
if (!is.null(table_q2)) HTML(table_q2)
```

In this example, you have to initialize `table_q2` to NULL when there is no `table_q2` output, otherwise rmarkdown complains.

Comment: This mostly works, but still has the r objects printed literally, so the `r q1_text` is printed instead of the text that is saved to that object via `q1_text <- "How many apples are in the basket?"`.  I think there might not be a solution for my problem because one a condition is met the subsequent information has to be evaluated either as _just_ HTML or evaluated and printed _just_ as an R object, but not both, such as when things are statically displayed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Based on your help, I was able to put something together that works (posted as an answer). Thank you!

Comment: Glad you were able to adapt the ideas offered to your specific situation!

Answer (score 0):

Using some of the solution suggested by @guasi, I was able to cobble together an inelegant, but workable solution by using the HTML function from the htmltools package:

```
{r, eval = has_two_qs, echo = FALSE}

tq2_1 <- "<table frame=hsides rules=rows>
  <tr>
    <td>SAQ Q2</td>
    <td>"
  
tq2_2 <- "</td>
  </tr>
  </table>"
```

And then:

```
{r, eval = has_two_qs, echo=FALSE}
library(htmltools)
library(knitr)

HTML(tq2_1)
asis_output(saq2_text)
HTML(tq2_2)
```

Comment: Continuing with above, it wasn't necessary to pre-save the information as r objects. I ended up just directly wrapping it in the HTML() argument, e.g., `HTML("<table><tr><td> SAQ Q2 </td> <td>")`. This became particularly useful because additional information / tables are also conditionally shown later in the document.